# Is there an advantage to beta-vs-Ic flatness in BJTs?

Tags: transistors

Something I've wondered. Some BJTs have flatter beta vs Ic than others in the graph provided in the datasheets. I realize the scales can mislead a bit but there are still differences. Some Toshiba and Sanken products are shown with seemingly perfect flat profiles at lower Ic.

Is there an advantage to such flatness (as opposed to variation part-to-part or vs temp)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117469/discussion-on-question-by-pete-w-is-there-an-advantage-to-beta-vs-ic-flatness-in).

Answer (score 3):

Let's pick a random audio power amp schematic from google images...

[image]

Output transistors (OPT) require base current Iout/hFe.

This creates a corresponding voltage drop on base resistors R25, R28 ; also the Vbe of the driver and predriver transistors (if any) will vary a bit according to OPT base current. This creates a voltage drop between the collector of Q4 and the output voltage which depends on Iout. Also, loading on VAS output (Q4 collector) depends on pre/drivers base current which depends on OPT base current.

If hFe gets lower at high current, then OPT base current will increase in non-linear fashion as output current increases. This creates a non-linear voltage drop between VAS output, and draws a non-linear current from VAS output. Both of these increase large signal distortion.

If hFe is constant, output transistor base current is proportional to Iout, therefore its effects on the preceding stages is linear.

TL/DR: power transistors with flat hFe vs Ic reduce non-linear loading on preceding stages at high current and thus produce lower large signal distortion.

Answer (score 0):

the question has been answered in the comments

jonk>> Pete, there's always cases where regions of relative flatness in \$h_\text{FE}\$ over some dynamic range of \$I_\text{C}\$ might be used to some advantage. Perhaps in a case where the BJT is analyzed using equipment capable of deriving a calibrated value for it and the BJT is only used in a pulsed situation where self-heating impacts over that dynamic range don't have enough time to also impact the value. That might allow the BJT to be used as some kind of calibrated sensor for some other purpose, I suppose. But this would be almost certainly for some rare/unique research lab goal.

jonk>> I thought of another use that is likely declining in its importance. It's possible that Tektronix or another maker of the earlier analog oscilloscopes might have preferred to select out BJTs with flatter \$h_\text{FE}\$ to improve their linearity on the scope. Back when BJTs were used discretely and not in ICs, anyway. Barrie Gilbert was pretty active there working on related topics, so I think it's possible that it mattered then. But I've only a guess and Barrie died, early this year, so I can no longer ask him about it.

Comment: Then put that answer from the comments in here.  The comments have been moved to chat, and not everyone can (or will) go there to read the solution.

Comment: Ok. But I didn't do that.

Comment: You can put your own answer/solution based on your understanding from the comments. You can accept it as solution as well. But don't just copy paste of others comments, which may get end up in getting flagged as spam and negative votes.

Comment: note DIRECTLY above: was instructed by site moderator to do so